# Maxima: how to replace cos(phi) with x

Tags: maxima

I have an expression `cos(phi) + sin(phi)`.
How can I convert this expression it to `x+y` with maxima, assuming that `cos(phi) is x`, and `sin(phi) is y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr: cos(phi) + sin(phi);
subst([cos(phi)=x, sin(phi)=y], expr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just

```
(%i1) cos(phi) + sin(phi), cos(phi) = x, sin(phi) = y;
(%o1) y + x
```